# Image not showing in activity

Tags: android

I'm manipulating images from one folder and saving it in other folder in internal memory .The other activity show all the images expect the images I'm manipulating but the images is saving in internal memory as I can check it through file manager.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
listItem = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: Are you getting the right URI ? Check twice .

Comment: put up the code were you are populating the UI and related code. Its hard to guess for anyone who reads your question without proper code samples and enough explanations

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Pick image. 
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

    // method for save image
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder Name");
    File file = new File(direct);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
 file = new File(file, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```